# Editable QML TableView depending on type

Tags: qt, qml

I have a QStandardItemModel which I display using a TableView in Qml. The data should be editable, and depending on the type of the data I would like to have different delegates, e.g. for a bool value a checkbox, for a string value a drop-down box of possible values. How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have a `Loader` that creates a different qml component depending on the model data.

Comment: Will this work also if there are different types in the same view (e.g. one line an int, the next one a bool)?

Comment: That's the whole idea. The loader creates a delegate according to the item type.

Comment: Use a delegateChooser instead, i can give you some examples if you want.

Comment: @Vkoder that is possible nowadays too, but my experience has taught me to not rely on QMLs "way too late in the game convoluted inflexible purpose specific one single static way to do a thing" stuff. Not if there is a simple generic way to do it. Because you start using something, then want to do things slightly different or specific, and it turns out this is problematic or outright impossible, and you are back to square one.

Comment: @dtech- did you have any issue with delegatechooser and anything else in specific? woul d be good to know.

Comment: @Vkoder not with this one, but I've had a lot of problems with qt model stuff in general, reported dozens upon dozens of bugs, most of which still unfixed. 12 years of experience with qt and qml taught me 1 - use as little qt as possible, 2 - make things as generic as possible. By the book stuff works, but once you try to do something outside the box and it breaks, here's a few examples I just recently discovered: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-108900 https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-108702 https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-108138

Comment: In the case of DelegateChooser, I'd rather just have an overridable functor that can source a component by whatever logic I want to implement, than getting stuck with a static DelegateChooser. Maybe I want something more fancy than just a role value for selection... Or what if I want to select the delegate based on TWO role values? No way to do that with the chooser, it works in its one specific way and is useless for anything other than that... I don't like "black boxes", I like power, control and flexibility.